# python heapq source code _siftdown

Tags: python

PYTHON:

```
def _siftdown(heap, startpos, pos):
    newitem = heap[pos]
    # Follow the path to the root, moving parents down until finding a place
    # newitem fits.
    while pos> startpos:
        parentpos = (pos - 1)>> 1
        parent = heap[parentpos]
        if cmp_lt(newitem, parent):
            heap[pos] = parent
            pos = parentpos
            continue
        break
    heap[pos] = newitem
```

I just looked at heapq source code and can anyone explain what the line 6 do? What is >> operator and how it works?

Comment: It's a [bitwise shift right operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types).

Comment: Following up on @dano, shifting right by one bit is the same as dividing by two and rounding down. A lot of traditional C, assembly, etc. implementations of heaps use the equivalent of `>> 1` instead of `// 2` because on older systems you'd generally get a huge speed improvement. Needless to say, that doesn't apply in Python, but having the code look more like what you'd find in a data structures textbook can be valuable. Also, some people (usually the ones who learned C or assembly) find that `>>` is a good signal that something is a logarithmic algorithm.

Comment: can I ask a follow up question. so this parentpos = (pos-1) >> 1 line is trying to return the index of its parent. But why minus 1? Say the current index is 4 which is the third level of the tree, and then you minus 1 get 3. And the binary number is 11, if you shift one right then it will be index 1, and its not the parent index.

Comment: You're forgetting that Python's `heapq` is 0-based. This is easy to forget, and can lead to confusion. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>>` operator means [bitwise right shift](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types). Shifting (nonnegative integers) right by one bit is equivalent to dividing by two and rounding down. In other words, `spam >> 1` and `spam // 2` are the same.

So, why use `>>`? Some CPUs—especially older ones—can do bit-shifting orders of magnitude faster than division. Most modern C compilers will optimize `n / 2` into `n >> 1` whenever appropriate, but older ones wouldn't. Of course that makes almost no difference in Python, but most traditional heap implementations—the kinds you'll see in data structures textbooks—will use `>>`. On top of that, to some people (the kind of people who learned from those textbooks), `>>` in an algorithm is a good signal that it's logarithmic.

---

> so this `parentpos = (pos-1) >> 1` line is trying to return the index of its parent. But why minus 1? Say the current index is 4 which is the third level of the tree, and then you minus 1 get 3. And the binary number is 11, if you shift one right then it will be index 1, and its not the parent index.

Read the top of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html):

> This implementation uses arrays for which `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+1]` and `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+2]` for all `k`…

So, for `k=1`, the children are `2*1+1 = 3` and `2*1+2 = 4`. As the next paragraph notes, this is potentially confusing:

> The API below differs from textbook heap algorithms in two aspects: (a) We use zero-based indexing. This makes the relationship between the index for a node and the indexes for its children slightly less obvious, but is more suitable since Python uses zero-based indexing.

So, you expect that the children of `1` are `2` and `3`, but if you think of it in 0-based terms, you should be expecting that the children of `0` are `1` and `2`, and the children of `1` are `3` and `4`.

Answer (score 1):

The `>>` is the right-shift operator.  It drop the rightmost bit which is the same as dividing by two and ignoring the remainder.  So that line could have been written `parentpos = (pos - 1)  // 2`.

Python's heaps are zero-based, so a node *i* has children at `2 * i + 1` and `2 * i + 2`.   And its parent is located at `(i - 1) // 2`.

What *siftdown* does is move a value upward (by swapping it with its parent) until the parent is smaller than the child.